# Rattling noise from Rear Right wheel Nissan Sentra

Tags: nissan, brake-rotor, brake-calipers, sentra, rattle

I have 2022 Nissan Sentra. As per Nissan’s service advise, I got my rear wheel Brake pads and rotors changed. And rear right wheel, I had to change calliper as well. But after installing everything I hear some kind of rattling noise from rear right wheel where i changed calliper, pads and rotor. Its not any braking noise, it comes when car goes over bumpy road or uneven road specially at lower speed. At high speed I do not hear anything. even with no gas/brake, I hear rattling noise on unever road at lower speed. Any suggestions on what could be the problem? Is it slider pins?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you gone back over all of the fasteners you loosened/removed during the work to ensure they are all tight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2022 Sentra uses anti-rattle clips on the rear brakes. The 8 stainless steel objects in the photo below. (Credit: Ebay)

If your anti-rattle clips were not installed or installed incorrectly, your brakes will . . . rattle! The pads will also wear out prematurely.

[image]

Comment: Great info. Thank you that was the issue. Car brakes are smooth now ✅