# Rattling brakes

Tags: brakes

Just had my brake pads and rotors replaced. Now there is rattling coming from both sides but**not** when I'm applying my brakes can someone please help with a possible problem it could be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question? I thought we just had a question about the same basic thing. The answer to the question was, on some cars, there are rattle clips, which if not installed or installed correctly, will allow the brakes to rattle. This could very well be your case. I'd suggest you take it back to the shop which did the work and tell them to fix their poo :o)

Comment: Link to the recent question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/92834/44030  The OP followed up and said this was indeed the problem; clips now installed and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like whomever installed the brakes did not install the anti rattle clips. These are generally a spring of sorts that applies pressure to the brake pads to prevent them from rattling. It could also be the case they popped off if they were installed incorrectly.